# consumptionState from Google Play Android Developer API

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I am writing a backend service to verify the in-app-purchase made from my android game. I am passing the purchase token to Google Play Android Developer API. The google API document here:https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/v1_1/inapppurchases
says the 'consumptionState' returned from the API, may be one of these values:

**0 - Consumed**

**1 - Yet to be consumed****

But from what I have tested, the values returned from the API seemed to be opposite, i.e.

**1 - Consumed**

**0 - Yet to be consume**

Can anyone confirm this?

Thanks

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm seeing the exact same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with you. *Google make a mistake on the document([1](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/v1_1/inapppurchases#resource)).*

The right one should be :

**1 - Consumed**

**0 - Yet to be consume**

Answer (score 1):

Unable to add a comment, but I agree.  The values I get back from the Purchase Status API do seem to be the opposite way to the API documentation.

I have confirmed that my unmanaged item purchases are consumed by my app code where appropriate, and each shows a consumptionState code of 1 via the API call on my server.  The one managed item I have, which is not consumed by the app shows a consumptionState code of 0.

I've submitted a bug report on the API documentation page, and will update here if I get any response.  https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/v1_1/inapppurchases#resource